# Is the "40% Slaves" modifier from Slavers Guilds empire wide or per planet?

Tags: stellaris

Pretty much the question title. I tried counting slaves in my empire and was only 2/3 of the way through my colonies when I got over 40%, but on many of them, I have more slaves than specialists. Is the civic bugged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's per planet per species. You have to take into account species on the planet that have species rights enslaving all of them. They don't follow that 40% rule. Also it might be the case that slavery and jobs get updated with some delay.